# Como escondo/conecto itens na navbar enquanto estiver logado

Tags: php, html, css

Estou fazendo um sistema de login ja está funciando normalmente o problema é que não sei como mudar o navbar enquanto o usuario estiver logado:

Codigo Index:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Redfield</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>    
            <img class="logo"src="AA.png" alt="">
            <ul class="navlist">
                <a href="index.php" style="text-decoration: none;">Home</a>
                <a href="/" style="text-decoration: none;">Launcher  </a>
                <a href="/" style="text-decoration: none;">Social Media  </a>
                <a href="login.php" style="text-decoration: none;">Login</a>
                </div>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <main>
        
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Codigo de verificação:

```
session_start();
include("checking.php");

if(empty($_POST['usuario']) || empty($_POST['password'])){
    header('Location: login.php');
    exit();
}

$usuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao ,$_POST['usuario']);
$senha = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao ,$_POST['password']);

$query = "select usuario_id from usuario where usuario = '{$usuario}' and senha = md5('{$senha}')";
$result = mysqli_query($conexao, $query);

$row = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($row == 1){
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
    header('Location: painel.php');
    exit();
    
}else{
    header('Location: login.php');
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dependendo da sessão (caso existir), você chama um arquivo PHP diferente no seu `painel.php`.
Vou dar nomes apenas para exemplificar: `navbarNaoLogado.php` e `navbarLogado.php`

**PHP:**

```
if(isset($_SESSION['usuario']) and !empty($_SESSION['usuario'])) {
    include_once(__DIR__.'/navbarLogado.php');
} else {
    include_once(__DIR__.'/navbarNaoLogado.php');
}
```

Ou seja, se a `$_SESSION['usuario']` existir e não estiver vazia, vai ser chamado o `navbarLogado.php`, caso contrário, vai ser chamado o `navbarNaoLogado.php`.